Mismatched GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport version in Podfile with Expo 52.0.9 and React Native 0.76.2
I am experiencing an issue with GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport in the Podfile when integrating react-native-firebase in my iOS project. Despite upgrading and downgrading the library versions, the problem persists. Below are the relevant details of my project and the error I am encountering.
Here are the relevant details of my setup:

Expo Version: 52.0.9

React Native Version: 0.76.2

react-native-firebase Version: 14.12.0

Xcode Version: 16.1 (16B40)

iOS Version: 15.1


Problem:
After installing react-native-firebase and resolving all dependencies, I’m getting a build failure due to mismatched versions of GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport. The error message I’m encountering is:
csharp

Copy code
[ERROR] Mismatched version of GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport in the Podfile.
Steps I’ve Tried:

Upgraded and downgraded react-native-firebase to different versions.

Ran pod repo update and pod install after clearing the derived data.

Manually modified the Podfile to try and resolve the version conflict, but nothing seems to work.


Podfile Snippet (Relevant Section):
ruby

Copy code
# Podfile platform :ios, '11.0' target 'MyApp' do use_frameworks! pod 'GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport', 'X.X.X' # Tried with different versions pod 'react-native-firebase', '~> 14.12.0' # Other dependencies end

Error Message:
bash

Copy code
[ERROR] Mismatched version of GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport in the Podfile.
Questions:

What is the correct version of GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport for react-native-firebase version 14.12.0 with React Native 0.76.2 and Expo 52.0.9?

How can I resolve the version mismatch in my Podfile?

Are there any other dependencies I should check to avoid version conflicts with Firebase SDKs in a React Native project?


Additional Information:

I’ve tried removing the version constraints in the Podfile for GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport but the issue persists.

I’ve checked the Firebase and react-native-firebase documentation for compatibility, but I'm still facing this issue.


